# How does the magic function mk_group_accessors work in DBIx::Class::Storage::DBI?

Tags: perl

```
  26 __PACKAGE__->mk_group_accessors('inherited' => qw/sql_maker_class sql_limit_dialect/);
    ...
  28
  29 __PACKAGE__->mk_group_accessors('simple' => qw/
  30   _connect_info _dbi_connect_info _dbic_connect_attributes _driver_determined
  31   _dbh _dbh_details _conn_pid _sql_maker _sql_maker_opts
  32   transaction_depth _dbh_autocommit  savepoints
  33 /);
  34
  35 # the values for these accessors are picked out (and deleted) from
  36 # the attribute hashref passed to connect_info
  37 my @storage_options = qw/
  38   on_connect_call on_disconnect_call on_connect_do on_disconnect_do
  39   disable_sth_caching unsafe auto_savepoint
  40 /;
  41 __PACKAGE__->mk_group_accessors('simple' => @storage_options);
```

I know `__PACKAGE__` means the current package but don't understand the others.

Comment: You want to know how it works, or what it does, or both?

Comment: The function is defined in [Class::Accessor::Grouped](http://search.cpan.org/~ribasushi/Class-Accessor-Grouped-0.10004/lib/Class/Accessor/Grouped.pm#mk_group_accessors).